# C++ Pointing to a dynamically created memory

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

Let me preface this by saying I am a c++ rookie, completely new and learning in school right now. One question I am stumped on is dynamically created memory and how to point back to it. For the assignment I have, I created the memory, printed in the console, then my task is to point back to dynamically created memory that I made at the beginning of the assignment. How do I do that? I must have to create a temporary variable or reference variable of some sort, but I'm just unsure of how to.

```
    // Task 1
//int *p;
int j = 18;
int *p = new int(2);
cout << "Dynamically created integer: " << *p << endl;
*p = j;
cout << "Named integer: " << *p << endl;
cout << "Return to dynamically created integer: " << *p << endl;
delete p;
```

That second to last line where I have the *p, that is incorrect, I just need to point back to the 3rd line of code somehow. Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be missing at least one step in the description of your assignment. Specifically: *"to point back to dynamically [allocated] memory that I made at the beginning of the assignment"* is rather trivial when the only step performed since that earlier memory allocation is to print something. Since nothing changed, you are already back where you started. (Where is the step that justifies the line `*p = j;` in your code?)

Answer (score 4):

You have a slight misunderstanding of how pointers work. We'll correct it here.

```
*p = j;
```

You think that this changes `p` to point to `j`. It does not. But let's proceed.

```
cout << "Named integer: " << *p << endl;
```

You are now thinking that this shows what `p` is pointing to now. And on the next line you want `p` to point to what it was, before.

Except that `p` is always pointing to the same thing, all the time. This line:

```
*p = j;
```

This does ***not*** point `p` to `j`. This sets the value that `p` points to, to the value of `j`. This is a very subtle difference. To change `p` to point to `j`, the correct syntax would be:

```
p = &j;
```

However, at this point, it becomes logically impossible to restore the original pointer. You have to save it first:

```
int *old_p=p;
p = &j;
```

Then, after you print what's `p` is pointing to now, you can simply restore it:

```
p=old_p;
```

And now the second print statement will show the original value that `p` was pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you're trying to get the memory location of j, for that you can use the "address of" ( & ) operator such as 'std::cout >> "memory address of j = " >> &j >> '\n';'